# What is faster (low network traffic) encoding for video only streaming? VP8 or jpeg?

Tags: encoding, video-streaming, jpeg, gstreamer, vp8

I'm making an open source project and I'm using gstreamer. What I want is to capture the input from camera and transmit to another IP address. What is faster to do with? vp8enc or jpegenc? If so what settings should I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not benchmark it and make the benchmarks part of your project? Will make your project more credible from the beginning.

Comment: I tested with gstreamer with both. But I cant test the bandwidth usage (don't know how to) since I'm sending and reciving streaming packets through loop back IP. Can you please provide me a benchmarking tool for gstramer? Would be lot of help than giving me the direct answer.

Comment: I can't help you with technical details. I was just suggesting this from a higher level point of view.

Comment: `iftop` will measure bandwidth usage. but you don't really need to go "over the wire": simply replace your netcasting element with a `filesink` and see how it grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn´t matter the codec that you use to have a very low bandwidth usage, it is just a matter of setting a very low bitrate in the encoder. But, of course, this would trade off the quality of the resulting video. The codec of the two cited that will give a better image quality for the same bitrate is the VP8. Just keep in mind to use the correct parameters for the encoder (using intra only in VP8 could result in an image quality worse than Motion JPEG)

Comment: Thanks friend. You gave the answer I'm looking for.